# How to prove that $m \mid \phi (a^m - 1)$ if $gcd(a,m) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

How to prove that $m \mid \phi (a^m - 1)$ if $gcd(a,m) = 1$

$\phi$ is euler function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Euler's theorem says that
$$b^{\phi(a^m-1)}\equiv 1\pmod{a^m-1}$$
when $\gcd(b,a^m-1)=1$.

Since $\gcd(a,a^m-1)=1$,
$$a^{\phi(a^m-1)}\equiv 1\pmod{a^m-1}$$

We have also that
$$a^m\equiv 1\pmod{a^m-1}$$

Note that $m$ is the order of $a$ in the multiplicative group $\Bbb Z_{a^m-1}^\times$, because $1<a^r<a^m$ if $0<r<m$.

Then $m\mid\phi(a^m-1)$.

I have not used that $a$ and $m$ are coprime. Are you sure that this is necessary?

Comment: Thank you! But why we know that $gcd(a,a^m-1) =1$?

Comment: If you do the Euclidean division $(a^m-1)/a$ you get $a-1$ as remainder. Just like $9999$ and $10$ are coprime.

Comment: @EugeneKorotkov If a prime $p$ divides $a$, then $p$ divides $a^m$, so $p$ doesn't divide $a^m-1$. Because otherwise $p$ divides $a^m-\left(a^m-1\right)=1$, contradiction.